# Parse iOS SDK: PFQueryTableViewController check for "Loading..."

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

**Scenario** = I have a PFQueryTableViewController (PFQTVC) with a UIView placed above the first row of the table view but below the nav bar at the top. This view has pictures as subviews and that view loads into the screen in the viewDidLoad method.

**Problem** = While the PFQueryTableViewController is loading it has a "Loading..." prompt that automatically gets placed in the middle of the screen and it stays there until it is finished loading the content for the PFQTVC. This makes for an ugly appearance when placed inevitably over the loaded UIView with the pictures on it.

**Question** = Does anyone know how to check (if statement) for when the PFQTVC is done loading it's content. Because then at that point I could says something like... (excuse the fake code)

```
if ([PFQTVC finishedLoading]) {

    self.view.hidden = NO;

}
```

This way, the UIView with my pictures on it won't be shown until the PFQTVC has finished loading and the "Loading..." prompt has been removed from the page. And the UIView will load the same time all of the cells from the PFQTVC will load.

**ANSWER** = (Thanks @valheru)

```
-(void)objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error {

    [super objectsDidLoad:error];

    self.loadingViewEnabled = YES;

    self.view.hidden = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Excerpt from: https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#ui-tables/iOS

> Loading View
>
> A loading view is displayed when the table view controller is loading
>   the first page of data. It is turned on by default, and can be turned
>   off via the property loadingViewEnabled.

You could just disable the loading view altogether, it looks like.

Additionally from their class reference, it looks like you can use objectsDidLoad to detect when they're loaded.

https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQueryTableViewController.html#//api/name/objectsDidLoad:

> objectsDidLoad:
>
> Called when objects have loaded from Parse. If you override this
>   method, you must call [super objectsDidLoad:] in your implementation.

```
- (void)objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error -
```

> Parameters error The Parse error from running the PFQuery, if there was any.
>
> Discussion Called when objects have loaded from Parse. If you override
>   this method, you must call [super objectsDidLoad:] in your
>   implementation.
>
> Declared In PFQueryTableViewController.h

Comment: Wow. You were exactly the eyes I was hoping would see my question. This works awesomely. I will post above my complete solution.